# Set root bone back into the object

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

How to set the root bone back to object after jumping through the fence?
I want to copy paste my walk cycle again from 1st frame

[image]

Comment: you can move the root, but you need to move back all the bones so that they match their last position in the global space

Answer (score 0):

When we doing this on character;

1. snap the 3d cursor to the hips
2. lock Z value on the root,  snap it to the 3d cursor
   this will push the character away
3. then snap the hips back to the 3d cursor so it comes back to where it is now